# Como hago para obtener igualar el valor de un id a a otro campo y crear un objeto a partir de ese campo

Tags: javascript, angular

Espero me puedan ayudar estoy usando angular select para traer toda la data, dicha data se ve de la siguente manera

```
[
    {id: 1, value: 'Ninguna'},
    {id: 2, value: 'Amenaza de Parto de Pretermino (APP)'},
]
```

este es el select

```
 <ng-select
      [items]="complications"
      multiple="true"
      bindLabel="name"
      [(ngModel)]="maternalComplicationsList"
    >
    </ng-select>
```

lo que necesito es obtener el id del dato seleccionado y luego anadirlo a un array con la siguiente estructura

```
[
 {
   complication: 1
 }
]
```

donde el 1 es el id seleccionado del select

Answer (score 1):

El ng-select tiene el output add cómo indica en su documentación https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#api puedes usar ese output para escuchar el evento y modificarlo cómo gustes

```
 <ng-select
      [items]="complications"
      multiple="true"
      bindLabel="name"
      [(ngModel)]="maternalComplicationsList"
     (add)="onAddItem($event)"
    >
    </ng-select>
```

Y en el component

```js
let array = [];
onAddItem(event) {
  console.log(event) // input agregado en el select
  // para crear un nuevo objeto con el id puedes hacer lo siguiente
  const {id} = event;
  array.push({complication: id});
}
```